# Unable to authenticate user in nodeJS:TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'username' in fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have a simple form that registers/authenticates users. I am able to successfully register a user, but unable to authenticate. I tried to research this problem, but I have not found anything that could be of help.

Here is html login form:

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
   <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">


</form>
```

When the user presses the `submit` button, the following shows up on my console:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'username' in fs
    at model.Document.$__buildDoc (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:207:39)
    at model.Document (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:61:20)
    at model.Model (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:45:12)
    at new model (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2957:11)
    at Strategy.model [as _verify] (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2956:14)
    at Strategy.authenticate (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:90:12)
    at attempt (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:348:16)
    at authenticate (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:349:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (/Users/userA/Desktop/loginapp/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:325:9)
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var User = require('./model/user.js');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var dbURL = 'mongodb://Admin:123@ds051655.mongolab.com:51655/yelpcamp';


mongoose.connect(dbURL, function(err) {
    err ? console.log(err) : console.log('successfully connected to db!');
});


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.use(session({
    secret:"sfsdfsdfsd",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User, User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {

    successRedirect: "/secret",
    failureRedirect: "/login"


}), function(req,res) {
});
```

user.js :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    pictures: [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Pictures"}],
    comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comments" }]  
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.1.0",
    "ejs": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.3.7",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

**update1**: To remedy this problem, I tried instantiating the User object in the user class (mongoose.Schema has been changed to  new mongoose.Schema). I also tried adding the Strategy property to `LocalPassport`. These mistakes were pointed out by gnerkus, but they failed to solve the issue as I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the `User` object is not being instantiated. This is because the model is invalid. A Mongoose schema should be created as an instance of the `mongoose.Schema` constructor. You'll need to refactor your model to use a `Schema` instance:

```
// Create instance of 'Schema' constructor.
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    pictures: [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Pictures"}],
    comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comments" }]  
});
```

Also, the `LocalStrategy` constructor is obtained from the `Strategy` object of `passport-local`. You need to replace this line:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
```

with this line:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this code, but the same problem persists.

Comment: I've discovered the solution. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I made the suggested change(which was basically adding the new before mongoose.Schema), but it didn't work; the same problem persists. 

However, thank you for pointing out this error (: